# Caption field with default value inside CKEditor

Tags: 8, media, wysiwyg

I activated the caption filter under Text format configuration to add description to media inserted via CKEditor

Is there a possibility to add a default value to this caption field whenever I add a new media inside the WYSIWYG editor?

[image]

Comment: The solution was inside `hook_form_alter`. I was unable to debug at first time inside this dialog popup, but using xdebug save me the day. Xdebug is a must have guys!